# Adding second TextView replaces the first TextView in a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout

I am adding `TextViews` programatically to a LinearLayout. But when the second TextView is added, it seems to replace the first.

Here is the code:

```
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts_container);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String username = object.getString("username");
        String status = object.getString("status");

// create wrapper
LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
wrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
wrapper.setPadding(padding,padding,padding,padding);
wrapper.setLayoutParams(lp);
l.addView(wrapper);

// add Imageview to wrapper
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_only_dark_crop);
lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
lp.setMargins(0, 0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 0);
image.setLayoutParams(lp);
wrapper.addView(image);


        // add linearLayout text wrapper to main wrapper
        LinearLayout textWrapper = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        textWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        textWrapper.setPadding(0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), 0, 0);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.9f);
        textWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
        wrapper.addView(textWrapper);

        // add username TextView to textWrapper
        TextView usernameText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        usernameText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        usernameText.setText(username);
        usernameText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        usernameText.setTextSize(0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        textWrapper.addView(usernameText);

        // add status TextView to textWrapper
        TextView statusText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        usernameText.setLayoutParams(lp);
        usernameText.setText(status);
        usernameText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        usernameText.setTextSize(0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        textWrapper.addView(statusText);


    }
```

It loops twice and two "wrapper" LinearLayouts get added to the main LinearLayout fine. But for each wrapper LinearLayout it should add two TextViews, but when I run the application, only the statusView displays. If I remove the statusView, the usernameView displays fine.

Why is that when the statusView is added to the wrapper, the usernameView seems to be hidden or removed?

Comment: Try  giving wrap_content as height to  textWrapper layout param.

Comment: It is a horizontal LinearLayout that wraps an ImageView and the textWrapper. I added both.

Comment: I have tried your code and, you are using usernameText for both the textViews. Change that to statusText for second view and it will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copy pasted the same layout variable name when initializing the second textview

use this instead

```
    // add username TextView to textWrapper
    TextView usernameText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    usernameText.setLayoutParams(lp);
    usernameText.setText(username);
    usernameText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    usernameText.setTextSize(0, (int)    TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    textWrapper.addView(usernameText);`

    // add status TextView to textWrapper
    TextView statusText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    statusText.setLayoutParams(lp);
    statusText.setText(status);
    statusText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    statusText.setTextSize(0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    textWrapper.addView(statusText);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your second textview, check the below text.

```
    TextView **statusText** = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    **usernameText**.setLayoutParams(lp);
    **usernameText**.setText(status);
    **usernameText**.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    **usernameText**.setTextSize(0, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    textWrapper.addView(statusText);
```

Comment: Ugh I should have stopped coding hours ago, sigh. Thanks.

Comment: i ve answered your question before aankit yet you accept his answer.

Comment: @crm Yeah, sometime it is good to take a break. :P Happy Coding mate

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `textWrapper` does'nt have a orientation specified. Define it as vertical or horizontal depending on your needs and it should work fine.

Comment: FYI: you don't have to specify an orientation unless you want it to be vertical. A `LinearLayout` has a horizontal orientation if none is specified.